# c# - How to return a correct checking float.Parse(String)?

Tags: c#

In my project I have a text box. I assume user type in it float variable or text.
If user types in it float variable I need to check this variable if it is actually a float type!.

I guess some how return `true` or `false` from `float.Parse(String)`. Is it possible?!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of `Parse`, use [`TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.tryparse.aspx) - it will return `false` if it couldn't parse.

```
float f;

if(float.TryParse(txtBox.Text, out f))
{
  // success! Use f here
}
```

Comment: int type can be checked the same way?

Answer (score 3):

Try using [`float.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.tryparse.aspx), which returns True if the string is a valid float.

```
float f = 0;
bool success = float.TryParse(stringToParse, out f);
```

Comment: There is no float.TryParse.

Answer (score 0):

I always prefer using Convert.ToWhatever() instead of Parse, because the Convert class can handle possibble null/incorrect values.

In you case, it would be

```
Convert.ToDecimal(input);
```